How can I modify my .htaccess to achieve this without overriding specific rules?
I have configured the following .htaccess rules to handle various URL rewrites for my project:
RewriteEngine On

# Base directory
RewriteBase /your_project/

# Specific rules for known paths
RewriteRule ^profile$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^messages$ profile_messages.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ajax/(.*)$ ajax.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^edit/(.*)$ edit_$1.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^my-account/(.*)$ myaccount_$1.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^my-account$ myaccount.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^invite/(.*)$ invite.php?key=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^invite$ invite.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ask-a-pro$ askapro.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^dashboard$ dashboardprj.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^dashboard-work$ dashboardprj_work.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^dashboard-new$ dashboard-new.php [QSA,L]

# General dynamic rule
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ project_management/plugin_management_design.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [QSA,L]

I want to handle dynamic URLs like:
https://www.example.com/dynamictitlefromtable1/idfromtable2/dynamictitlefromtable2
However, the issue is that all URLs are being captured by the general dynamic rule:
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ project_management/plugin_management_design.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [QSA,L]

This causes conflicts with my specific rules (e.g., /profile, /messages, /invite, etc.).
Goal:
I want to ensure that:

Specific rules (like /profile, /messages, /ajax/, etc.) take
priority.
Only dynamic URLs with the pattern
/dynamictitlefromtable1/idfromtable2/dynamictitlefromtable2 are
captured by the general rule.


Not to sure on the subject of rewriting rules. But what I see whenever I have to deal with them are rewrite conditions. The way I understand them is that you can influence when a rule kicks in. Perhaps worth investigating?

As per this meta post and this meta post this question is not at all off-topic for SO so close vote is wrong. This has been discussed again and again and it has been settled already that most of the rewrite rules are created and maintained by developers of the web applications/frameworks. @amit-verma

This causes conflicts with my specific rules (e.g., /profile, /messages, /invite, etc.).: Can you provide more details on this. What behaviour are you seeing and what is your expectation?

This belongs on Webmasters site

@RohitGupta: Please check 2 meta posts I have shared above.  There are more than 70K Q&A on .htaccess tag here on SO.
